# Hyperledger Fabric, stop parallel chaincode execution

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

all so I have a problem with hyperledger fabric why it is allowed the chaincode to be executed parallel in hyperledger like this:

```
running push()
2
ending push()
running push()
1
ending push()
running push()
3
ending push()
running push()
5
ending push()
running push()
4
ending push()
```

So what I am doing here is:
   - Creating new transaction and sending 2 objects than
   - Immediately sending another transaction

so before the ledger is update the key should be for example: 3 + 2 = 5 and than again 5 + 1 = 6

but this is wrong in this case because it starts with: 3 + 2 = 5 and before updating the ledger another push is done from the current key 3 + 1 = 4 and not from 5 + 1 = 6.

how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I) 
keep in mind that a chaincode execution is just a simulation of the smart contract logic computation.
In other words - the chaincode execution tells you **what would be the update to the channel, if the transaction would be committed**.

When the client gets back the endorsement from the peer (containing the simulation) - it sends it to the orderer to be scheduled to appear in some block in the next available batch that would cut a block.

Only when the block is persisted into the ledger (and only if the transaction is valid - meaning, it wasn't invalidated by any other transaction in a prior block or in a prior transaction within the block it came from) - next chaincode executions may see the changes of the transaction.

(II)

> why it is allowed the chaincode to be executed parallel in hyperledger
>   like this:

So, from (I) it follows that there is no point **not** to execute the chaincode in parallel, since in any case the end of the chaincode execution doesn't mean that the next execution would read that data.

Comment: yes, but the second transaction doesn't get commited

Comment: probably because it encounters an MVCC conflict

Comment: MVCC = Multi version concurrency control
Probably the 2nd transaction reads some key that was written to during a previous transaction.

Comment: yes this is my problem, and how can I handle this MVCC ?

Comment: There is no way around it, it's the Fabric model that focuses on separation between consensus (ordering) and smart contract execution (chaincode).
It allows independent operations to be done concurrently but not dependent ones (to tackle double spending)